# Shorten this IF statement in PHP

Tags: php

I want to cut if statement and make it best way

```
if ($box === 1) {
    $message['sender'] = $data['user_profile_id'];
    $message['receiver'] = $data['to_user_profile_id'];
} else {
    $message['sender'] = $data['to_user_profile_id'];
    $message['receiver'] = $data['user_profile_id'];
}
```

1 attempt:

```
$message['sender'] = $box === 1 ? $data['user_profile_id'] : $data['to_user_profile_id'];
$message['receiver'] = $box === 1 ? $data['to_user_profile_id'] : $data['user_profile_id'];
```

is there better way to switch sender/receiver vars ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the first statement.

Comment: If find it good already. What you could eventually do is assign both sender and receiver with a default value, and in your if or else statement, just change the one needing to be changed in that case, but that's no big improvement...or not even an improvement actually.

Comment: It's good any there is no "field" for improving. It's very simple code. You only make shorter syntax that's all.

Comment: Don't ask how to make code shorter. Rather, ask yourself how to make code more *understandable*.

Comment: "make it best way" - the "THE BEST" problem. What do you want to optimize? Speed? Simplicity? Readability? Making it coding error "resistant"? ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your first statement looks good, but you could make your second example a bit shorter, but it's just not worth it in my opinion:

```
$message['sender'] = $data[($box===1 ? 'to_' : '_') .'user_profile_id'];
$message['receiver'] = $data[($box===1 ? '_' : 'to_') .'user_profile_id'];
```